# Xamarin ZXing QR Code inside tab

Tags: android, xamarin, fragment

I would like to integrate ZXing QR code scanner into my app. 
I am using Fragment for my tabs. 
For example in Tab2, how I can add a window to show the scanner view?
I tried to use CustomOverlay with view but unfortunately it did not work. I also tried to use ZXingScannerFragment,but it requires Android.Support.V4.App which is not ideal as all my other two tabs uses Android.App namespace. 
Where I am at right now is that, when Tab 2 is selected, it jumps straight to the scanner, and the Action Bar and Tabs becomes invisible.
Can anyone please shed some light on this? 
Thank you very much.

```
        _fragments = new Fragment[]
                     {
                         new Fragment1(),
                         new Fragment2(),
                         new Fragment3()
                     };            

        AddTabToActionBar(Resource.String.whatson_tab_label, Resource.Drawable.ic_action_whats_on);
```

[image]

Comment: Have you found a solution?